# CQ5.6.1 - JSESSIONID cookie is not getting created in one of the Production servers but gets created in other servers?

Tags: java, session, aem, sessionid

We have 3 servers, out of those in 2 servers JSESSIONID cookie is not getting created but in another server it gets created. Due to this we are probably facing the issue of request.getsession() as null. Can anyone please help? Is there any specific changes that needs to be done in-order to create JSESSIONID cookie automatically? We are using version CQ5.6.1

Comment: Is it the same domain name for all servers?

Comment: Yes the domain is same. Only dispatchers are different for each servers. And all of them are connected in load-balancer. But I am checking directly through the IP of each publish servers only.